# Cloudfront Access denied

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cloudfront

I'm trying to create a Cloudfront with an S3 origin using Cloudformation. I want to restrict the S3 objects to be only accessible through Cloudfront. However, I'm getting access denied using both S3 direct url and Cloudfront url.

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"
Resources:
  S3Bucket:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
    Properties:
      AccessControl: Private
  CloudFrontOriginIdentity:
    Type: 'AWS::CloudFront::CloudFrontOriginAccessIdentity'
    Properties:
      CloudFrontOriginAccessIdentityConfig:
        Comment: 'origin identity'
  BucketPolicy:
      Type: 'AWS::S3::BucketPolicy'
      Properties:
        Bucket: !Ref S3Bucket
        PolicyDocument:
          Statement:
            - Effect: Allow
              Principal:
                AWS: !Sub 'arn:aws:iam::cloudfront:user/CloudFront Origin Access Identity ${CloudFrontOriginIdentity}'
              Action: 's3:GetObject'
              Resource: !Sub 'arn:aws:s3:::${S3Bucket}/*'
  CloudFrontDistribution:
    Type: 'AWS::CloudFront::Distribution'
    Properties:
      DistributionConfig:
        DefaultCacheBehavior:
          AllowedMethods:
            - GET
            - HEAD
            - OPTIONS
          CachedMethods:
            - GET
            - HEAD
            - OPTIONS
          Compress: true
          DefaultTTL: 3600
          ForwardedValues:
            Cookies:
              Forward: none
            QueryString: false
          MaxTTL: 86400
          MinTTL: 60
          TargetOriginId: s3origin
          ViewerProtocolPolicy: 'redirect-to-https'
        DefaultRootObject: 'index.html'
        Enabled: true
        HttpVersion: http2
        Origins:
          - DomainName: !GetAtt 'S3Bucket.DomainName'
            Id: s3origin
            S3OriginConfig:
              OriginAccessIdentity: !Sub 'origin-access-identity/cloudfront/${CloudFrontOriginIdentity}'
```

In the S3, I got index.html with just Hello inside of it.

Created bucket policy

```
{
"Version": "2008-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::cloudfront:user/CloudFront Origin Access Identity xxxxxxxxxxxx"
        },
        "Action": "s3:GetObject",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mystack-s3bucket-xxxxxxxxxxx/*"
    }
]
}
```

Comment: Can you post the bucket policy that CFn created?

Comment: @jellycsc added

Answer (score 0):

I deployed your template in my sandbox account. It **works as expected**. The bucket, policy, CF distro are all fine and my sample website works.

Just make sure you are using CF domain name to access your static website from the internet, not the bucket url, as I've seen people using bucket url by mistake with CF. It will have form of

```
ddd7asdf234sa.cloudfront.net
```

Comment: I get Access denied from both, CF and s3 urls, with that exact template. Could it have something to do with the S3 file permissions etc?

Comment: @Jayp Have you modified them? Whatever is happening, this is not the fault of the template you've posted.